# Why an attacker needs ~2^128 computing power to spoof membership of a key/value pair in a trie?

Tags: attacks, state-trie, merkle-patricia-tries

[Ethereum Wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#merkle-patricia-trees):

> Every unique set of key/value pairs maps uniquely to a root hash, and
>   it is not possible to spoof membership of a key/value pair in a trie
>   (unless an attacker has ~2^128 computing power)

I did not understand the statement shown above, where:

**[Q]** Why an attacker needs ~2^128 computing power to spoof membership of a key/value pair in a trie?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.